# Magento 2.26 Error on Manage Post (No show any post)

Tags: magento2

I'm working on Magento 2.2.6 but in Manage Post don't show any post through I had create 3 posts.

Please give me directions to solve this problem!!!

Thanks all!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZAH.jpg)

Comment: You've probably got a javascript error. Can you post the console log please?

Comment: Thanks you! I fixed it by reinstall source :D